# How to use defaultNavigationOptions's properties with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

When we try to use tabBarLabel property in defaultNavigationOptions in Typescript we get an error about type.

I've tried the code in Javascript and I don't get an error.
If we use only the barTabIcon the code works.

I've installed the libraries with the types: '@types/react-navigation[...]' but nothing.

How can I solve this problem? Any ideas?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Image, View} from 'react-native';
import {
  createAppContainer,
  createBottomTabNavigator

} from 'react-navigation';


import AccountScreen from '../tabmenu/AccountScreen';
import CarteScreen from '../tabmenu/CarteScreen';
import OperazioniScreen from '../tabmenu/OperazioniScreen';


const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({

    Account: {screen: AccountScreen},
    Carte: {screen: CarteScreen},
    Operazioni: {screen: OperazioniScreen}
 }, {
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({

            tabBarIcon: ({focused, horizontal, tintColor}) => {

                //inserire switch
                const {routeName} = navigation.state;
                if (routeName === 'Account') {
                    return (
                        <Image
                            source= . 
{require('../../../res/drawable/faq.png')}
                            style={{width: 20, height: 20,}}/>


                    );
                } else {
                    return (
                        <Image
                            source= . 
{require('../../../res/drawable/faq.png')}
                            style={{width: 20, height: 20}}/>
                    )
                }
            },

            tabBarLabel: ({focused, tintColor}) => {
                const {routeName} = navigation.state;
                let label;
                switch (routeName) {
            case 'Account':
            return label = focused ?<Text>Account</Text>:null;
            case 'Carte':
            return label = focused ? <Text >Carte</Text> :null;
            case 'Appointments':
            return label = focused ?<Text>Operazioni</Text> : null;

                }
                return label
            },


        }
    ),


   }
);

class HomeScreen extends Component {

    render() {

        return (

            <View style={styles.container}>

                <TabNavigator/>

            </View>
        );
    }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
          [...]
});

export default createAppContainer(TabNavigator);
```

Answer (score 2):

The types of react-navigation are very complex. And the usability there is no match to React's types. It took me way too much time to figure the types out and I wish nobody else has to do this again. So here you go.

- Second argument of `createBottomTabNavigator()` is of type
  `BottomTabNavigatorConfig`.
- Its property `defaultNavigationOptions` is of type `NavigationBottomTabScreenOptions` or

```
(
  navigationOptionsContainer: NavigationScreenConfigProps & {
    navigationOptions: NavigationScreenConfig<NavigationBottomTabScreenOptions>;
  }
) => NavigationBottomTabScreenOptions
```

- This function needs to return `NavigationBottomTabScreenOptions` which has two properties you are interested in:

  - Property `tabBarIcon` of type `React.ReactElement<any>` or
    `(options: TabBarIconProps) => React.ReactElement<any> | null`
  - Property `tabBarLabel` of type `string` or `React.ReactElement<any>` or
    `(options: TabBarLabelProps) => React.ReactElement<any> | string | null`

This makes your function `tabBarIcon` look like this:

```
const tabBarIcon = (options: TabBarIconProps):React.ReactElement<any> => {
  const {focused, horizontal, tintColor} = options;
  const {routeName} = navigation.state;
  if (routeName === 'Account') {
    return <Image {...}/>;
  } else {
    return <Image {...}/>;
  }
}
```

and the function `tabBarLabel` like this:

```
const tabBarLabel = (options:TabBarLabelProps):React.ReactElement<any>|null => {
  const {focused, tintColor} = options;
  const {routeName} = navigation.state;
  // I've removed the undefined variable "label" and added instead a default clause
  switch (routeName) {
    case 'Account':
      return label = focused ? (<Text>Account</Text>) : null;
    case 'Carte':
      return label = focused ? <Text >Carte</Text> : null;
    case 'Appointments':
      return label = focused ? <Text>Operazioni</Text> : null;
    default:
      return null;
  }
}
```

So once that is out of the way we can get back to the `defaultNavigationOptions`

```
const defaultNavigationOptions = (navigationOptionsContainer: NavigationScreenConfigProps):NavigationBottomTabScreenOptions => {
  return {
    tabBarIcon: tabBarIcon,
    tabBarLabel: tabBarLabel,
  }
}
```

Then add the missing imports and you should be done.